# Navigate from opened In-app Web browser back to the previous ionic page on react app

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router

I am building an ionic react app, I have a button in PageView-A that opens an in-app web browser to fill a web form hosted on a website. Once the users have finished and submitted the form, I want to return them to a certain page in the app.

This is how I am launching the InAppBrowser in PageView-A:

```
<IonItem
  routerDirection={undefined}
  onClick={() => Browser.open({
     url: 'http://www.myweb.com/myform.html'
  })}
>
  <IonLabel>Fill Survey</IonLabel>
</IonItem>
```

Is that possible with react and ionic? or maybe return to the same page and fire a specific method?

Comment: Where are you wanting to navigate the user to? Typically you can just issue a navigation action after calling `openInAppBrowser`, possibly after a small delay.

Comment: Either to the previous react app page or a new one. Or maybe the same previous page but executing a specific method. The idea is how I can know that the user filled and submitted the form in the web browser

Comment: I see, ok so your question isn't just about the back navigation, but more about needing to know the status of events in the other window. Nothing immediately comes to mind other than perhaps a socket connection or something similar that allows these two pages to "talk".